# com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection@36d4f39c: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: dual not found

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss7.x, sybase

I have upgraded sybase data base driver from **jconn3.jar** to **jconn4.jar** in my project. I get the below error when my application connects to Sybase data source. I have deployed my application on JBOSS 7 server.

```
[org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory] (default task-48) IJ030027: Destroying connection that is not valid, due to the following exception: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection@36d4f39c: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: dual not found. Specify owner.objectname or use sp_help to check whether the object exists (sp_help may produce lots of output).
at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.processEed(Tds.java:4131)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.nextResult(Tds.java:3247)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ResultGetter.nextResult(ResultGetter.java:78)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(SybStatement.java:294)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(SybStatement.java:276)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.executeLoop(SybStatement.java:2828)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.execute(SybStatement.java:2815)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.execute(SybStatement.java:1447)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.CheckValidConnectionSQL.isValidConnection(CheckValidConnectionSQL.java:74)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.isValidConnection(BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.java:1272)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.getInvalidConnections(BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.java:1085)
```

What does **'dual not found'** in the error mean?
Can you please let me know what is the root cause of this issue and help to resolve it?

My data source configuration is shown below :

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/SybaseDS" pool-name="SybaseDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
    <connection-url>*********************</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver</driver-class>
    <driver>sybase</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
    </pool>
    <validation>
        <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1 from dual</check-valid-connection-sql>
        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.sybase.SybaseExceptionSorter"/>
     </validation>
     <timeout>
          <set-tx-query-timeout>false</set-tx-query-timeout>
          <blocking-timeout-millis>0</blocking-timeout-millis>
          <idle-timeout-minutes>15</idle-timeout-minutes>
          <use-try-lock>0</use-try-lock>
          <allocation-retry>0</allocation-retry>
          <allocation-retry-wait-millis>0</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
      </timeout>
      <statement>
            <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
      </statement>
  </datasource>
```

Comment: What is your datasource config. It looks like you have a validity check that does `select * from dual` or something like that. Does Sybase actually have a `dual` table (I believe that is an Oracle specific thing)?

Comment: @Mark Thanks for response. I have included data source config in my question. I too suspect something is wrong in data source config. What needs to be changed or removed here?

Comment: As I said, I guess(!) your validation query is wrong, because I believe (but don't know for sure), that Sybase has no table called `dual`. And if it does exist, your user doesn't have rights to that table. Replace it with a (simple) query that does work on Sybase.

Comment: Thanks Mark. It works after removing the dual validation query from the data source.I will post the answer. Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

I will resolved this issue by removing the connection validation query in the data source as shown below :

```
<check-valid-connection-sql>select 1 from dual</check-valid-connection-sql>
```

The dual table doesn't exist in Sybase database.